# Algorithm to assign maximum Jobs to a person, and can have some jobs left out

Tags: algorithm, task

(Before anyone asks, this is not homework.)

I am just trying to figure out a way to optimize the way to assign maximum jobs possible to be assigned to a person keeping in account the multiple, minimum thresholds.

Let's say the users can be assigned a max of Job weight J100.

For example, if i have 2 users, A & B and the minimum threshold is T10, T20 & T30, and Job sizes [J5,J10,J15,J20]

let start with the big size jobs to small size jobs, i.e J20

Since A & B can both pick the job, the user can be randomly picked, and let's say we picked A (J20, also user reached the T1 and T2).

Moving on to the second job i.e J15, since A already reached the first threshold, it is only possible to assign this to B,

```
A (J20, reached T1 and T2)
B (J15, reached T1)
```

Going on with third job i.e J10, and all the person has reached the first threshold, we move on to the second threshold
Since A already reached the threshold T2 B will be only eligible for this job

```
A (J20, reached T1 and T2)
B (J15, J10, reached T1 and T2)
```

Going on with the last job, i.e 5,
Both A and B are capable of getting jobs. However, only User B is able to reach the next threshold of T30 i,e (J15+J10+(J5)=J30) hence should only pick user B

```
Hence

A (J20, reached T1 and T2)

B (J15, J10, J5 reached T1 & T2 & T3)
```

Now there if the total work size is W5, i.e it is not possible to assign this to any user since it won't reach the threshold T10, hence this job will be not assigned.

So I am trying to figure out an optimum algorithm that considers the thresholds and is greedy to assign the task to the users.

There is also a chance that job will be unassigned and users will not have jobs.

Comment: Meta-suggestion: formulate as an integer program, use a solver library. I'm partial to the [CP-SAT Solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) from OR-Tools (but full disclosure, the devs are colleagues of mine).

Comment: Thanks @DavidEisenstat, the tool seems cool. Giving it a try !